# PHP Login Sessions - "Logged in" pages using header(

Tags: php, mysql, security, session, authentication

I have a question about Sessions, and validating a logged in user.

My question is about sending the user to a "logged in" page, ie. profile page

```
if ($num_rows > 0) {
session_start();
$_SESSION['login'] = "1";
header ("Location: profile.php");
}
```

Does this mean any page that only a logged in user can view must have a php extension.

If it was for example, profile.html, then anyone who knows where that file is could view it right?

So would every profile page have a .php extention?  and inside this php file, is the html code for forms and whatnot?

Comment: you can can have your server pass any or all files through the php engine, file names and extensions are meaningless.

Comment: If your profile page has code which verifies and uses the php $_SESSION["login"] variable, then it must be a php file (contain php scripts).  Technically the extension doesn't matter, as Dagon said, as long as the php engine can interpret the file.

Comment: this is a very common necessity of websites. There are already many solutions which will simplify the database and login coding. I recommend a PHP framework like codeigniter to help out with this, which has an addon for user control.

Comment: Wow, I thanks a bunch for pointing out codigniter.  Not sure why I didn't think of that before.  Obviously it has been done and no need to re-invent...Any drawbacks to using something like this.  Seems amazing to me.  Should save me some time.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a short code to each PHP page that validates if the user is logged in and if not you redirect the user to a login page (you can also save the referal to bring him back to the page he wanted to visit).

So the short answer is yes you will need code in every page to validate the user.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write your login system in php, every page need to have the php extension because you need to check on every page if the user is logged in.

if you don't want to use php you could also use .htaccess files for the login system

Comment: wrong. you all tell the serve to pass .html or anything else as php

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.  It seems like I will have more php files than html files, even if the php file has a few lines of php code and mostly html code.  Is this normal?

Comment: no, if you want to run php code from a file with html extension, you need do configure your webserver

AddType application/x-httpd-php .html

Comment: So do most sites have all their files with php extensions, and run html code needed from inside there.  I feel sites with log out buttons on every page need to have a php extension to make sure the user is logged in, and display a log out button

Answer (score 0):

To ensure that a single point of entry is maintained, htaccess can be utilized to     ensure no other file may be accessed, and that we hide the index.php file in the url.

```
The .htaccess file itself looks like this-

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?rt=$1 [L,QSA]



The .htaccess file will permit access to the site via urls such as
http://www.example.com/news/show


If you do not have mod_rewrite available, the entry to the site will be the same,    except that the URL will contain the values needed such as:
http://www.example.com/index.php?rt=news/show
```

Comment: Hhmm I'm not sure I fully get this.  At first glance it looks like a way to not have a million directories with index.php/html files to keep urls clean.

I do not get how it helps with my problem with logged in users.  A logged in users goes to example.com/profile, and whether i have a profile folder with a index.php, or this i get the same result.

Answer (score 0):

### So should every profile page have a .php extention?

I would say yes. If your checking the session global variable using php script in each and every profile page then you need to have .php extension because it is the script that is going to run in your server.

If your profile page is not login protected or if your not checking for session global variable using php script then .html extension works fine for profile page.

Source :
[Login Password Protected Page using Sessions | PHP](http://codispatch.blogspot.in/2015/07/php-login-password-protected-page-sessions.html)